# Filtering the data showed on index page using parameter received in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models here for Item and RecipeIngredient as below where RecipeIngredient belongs to Item.

---

### Model for Item

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_type, :class_name=>ItemType, :foreign_key=>"item_type_id"
end
```

---

### Model for RecipeIngredient

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, :class_name=>Item, :foreign_key=>"item_id"
  belongs_to :ingredient, :class_name=>Ingredient, :foreign_key=>"ingredient_id"
  validates_numericality_of :quantity
end
```

I have index page for Items where I have created a link to index page for RecipeIngredients and I am passing the id of the item in the URL as parameter.

---

### Index Page for Item

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Items</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Item type</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.item %></td>
        <td><%= item.item_type.item_type %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Add Recipe', recipe_ingredients_path(:item_id =>item.id) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
<%= link_to "Home", '/' %>
```

And I have the controller for RecipeIngredients as below.

---

### Controller for RecipeIngredient

```
  def index
    @recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.find(params[:item_id])
  end
```

And the index page for recipe ingredients looks like as given below. I need to filter the data displayed on this index page of recipe ingredients only to match the item_id received as a parameter in URL.

---

### Index for RecipeIngredients

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Recipe Ingredients</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Ingredient</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.item.item %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.ingredient.ingredient %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.ingredient.recipe_unit %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', recipe_ingredient %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_ingredient_path(recipe_ingredient) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe_ingredient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Recipe Ingredient', new_recipe_ingredient_path %>
<%= link_to 'Back', '/items' %>
```

Right now I am getting this error:

> undefined method `show' for #< RecipeIngredient:0xa5653b8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.find(params[:item_id])
```

This will return you only one `RecipeIngredient` with `id = params[:item_id]` not activerecord array

So you need to change `find` to `where` if you want to loop over `@recipe_ingredients`

```
@recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where(params[:item_id])
```

or, you need to change the view

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @recipe_ingredients.item.item %></td>
    <td><%= @recipe_ingredients.ingredient.ingredient %></td>
    <td><%= @recipe_ingredients.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= @recipe_ingredients.ingredient.recipe_unit %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', @recipe_ingredients %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_ingredient_path(@recipe_ingredients) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @recipe_ingredients, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I changed the controller as below

Comment: I changed the controller as below

Comment: I changed the controller to **@recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where(params[:item_id])** and now it shows the index page but it does not filter the results using the parameter.

Comment: Got it! Had to change my controller to **@recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where(:item_id => params[:item_id])**